# Maven: how to copy a directory cleanly before creating the JAR?

Tags: maven

I want to store some additional files in the JAR that gets created. Those files are in a directory that is a subdirectory of a repository which is pulled in via a git submodule.

I want to copy that submodule to my src resources directory before compiling, but I also want to make sure that any old files at that location are removed first.

How can that be achieved best with Maven plugins? I did not find any option to remove any destination files with the copy-resources goal of the maven-resources-plugin and I could not get the maven-clean-plugin to run right before the copy-resources either. So how does one accomplish such a trivial task with Maven?

UPDATE: as mentioned above, the reason why I want to do this is because what is copied should become part of what gets added to the resulting jar (and could potentially be part of what gets compiled). So I need to copy these files into the src directory and NOT the target directory. What should get copied before each build is the input to the build, not an additional output.

Comment: Please post your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

There is one flaw in your approach, and it probably explains most of the obstructions you encountered.

During a build, the only directory in which you may write is `target`. Copying files to `src` or changing them is strictly discouraged.

The `target` folder is erased by `clean`, so no need to tidy up yourself or to manage old files.

Comment: OK, so Maven tries to tell me what I want, but what I want is to copy into src.
Is Maven really that bad in this respect as well (it is already terrible in almost every other respect) that it refuses to do what I want?

Comment: Maven follows a relatively strict philosophy about how builds should (and should not) work. If you use Maven and do _not_ follow the Maven philosophy, you likely run into problems (I learned that the hard way - I tried to "trick" Maven and regretted it later).

Comment: To your specific situation: If you only create files in `target`, you have several advantages: 1. You can easily `clean` by removing the content of `target`. 2. You don't create changes that might accidentally be committed into your git. 3. Having a reproducible build is much easier.

Comment: But the aim is to put data into src/main/resources so that the resources can get included in the JAR. So it is obvious that we need to copy to something that is explicitly not the target already!

Comment: You can also include resources from the `target`.

Comment: Thanks maybe I should do it like that then, thanks for helping!
But with regard to Maven (not the answer) I do not think it makes sense to use the target as a source for something to build that gets then put into the target, logically. Just another illustration of how badly designed maven really is. Grrrr.